# Remove ^M from CSV file

Tags: javascript, csv, carriage-return

Trying to read CSV formatted data into javascript using the [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) library, but am getting a `CSVDataError: Illegal Data` error from the `^M` character at the end of each line.

It seems no matter how a CSV is saved, I get this `^M`. I can only ever see the `^M` if I open the CSV file in `vim`, even in a text editor or my IDE the data looks fine. I don't get this problem when working in other languages either such as Python or R.

I am working on a Mac environment.

How can I fix this and avoid this problem in the future?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `dos2unix` to convert.
2. It's false that "no matter how it is saved" the CR (^M is a carriage return) is appended. For instance, `echo 'a,b,c' > letters.csv` does not append a CR. Check your text editor settings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [splitlines algorithm](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/wiki/Algorithms) on the jquery-csv page, it seems to provide a function that will clean these problematic carriage returns for you.

Comment: How do I implement this splitLines algorithm?

Comment: So after I read my csv data into javascript, I call that function, then pass the result into my csv.toArrays() function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `^M` indicates a mac-style carriage return, support for carriage return was included in a previous release so your code should just work.

*Source: I'm the author of jquery-csv*